# Autowired on Constructor with parameters fails

Tags: spring, spring-context

I have following sample code:

### **Bean class:**

```
package com.example.learn1.bean;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class Bean1 {

    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Bean1() {
        System.out.println("Inside Bean1() constructor");
    }

    @Autowired
    public Bean1(String name, int id) {
        System.out.println("Inside Bean1(String name, int id) constructor");
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Bean1(String name) {
        System.out.println("Inside Bean1(String name) constructor");
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Bean1(int id) {
        System.out.println("Inside Bean1(int id) constructor");
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**The below is main app, here I am trying to autowire bean1.**

```
package com.example.learn1.main;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.learn1.bean.Bean1;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.learn1" })
@Component
public class MainApp {

    @Autowired
    Bean1 bean1;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MainApp.class);
        System.out.println("Inside main, ctx is --> " + ctx);
        MainApp t = ctx.getBean(MainApp.class);
        t.print();
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Inside MainApp#print() method");
    }
}
```

The program works fine when I don't keep `@Autowire` on constructor `public Bean1(String name, int id)`. By default it calls the no-argument constructor viz: `public Bean1()`. The moment I use `@Autowire` on constructor `public Bean1(String name, int id)`, it fails.

So does it work only on no-argument Constructor? How can I make it work for Constructor with arguments?

### **The below is the exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainApp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bean1'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bean1' defined in file [/Users/vkoul/eclipse-workspace/spring-framework-learning/target/classes/com/example/learn1/bean/Bean1.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88)
    at com.example.learn1.main.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:37)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bean1' defined in file [/Users/vkoul/eclipse-workspace/spring-framework-learning/target/classes/com/example/learn1/bean/Bean1.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1651)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Could you please show us the exception?

Comment: I think you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/50604533/4597596 to see how a parameterized constructor can be Auto-wired and used.

Comment: And why did you use @Autowired on that constructor? what exactly do you inject in your class?

Comment: @MehrdadHosseinNejad: I am trying to create `Bean1` using `@Autowired` in `MainApp`. By default, it invoked no-argument constructor. I was checking how to create this `Bean1` by calling non-argument constructor. Isn't that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Autowired
public Bean1(String name, int id) {
    System.out.println("Inside Bean1(String name, int id) constructor");
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}
```

Tells to the container to inject 2 beans (one bean of type `String` called `name` and the other one called `id` of type `int`) when the constructor is used to instantiate `bean1`.
Where did you defined those beans? Also note that creating beans from primitive types is not common, that does not mean you can't.

For primitive type we generally declared them in `application.properties` and then inject them using `@Value`.

Comment: For simplicity i kept primitives, I can very well keep some Objects. My question is more inclined towards how to inject using a constructor which has arguments.

Comment: As I said in my answer `Where did you define those beans?`. If you want to inject beans as constructor parameters, you have to define them first. So define 2 beans of type `String` and `int` then they will be picked and injected into your constructor.

Comment: @akumar8: Thanks for your inputs. So if we do `@Autowired` on a `field`, why do we still need to define a `constructor` or a `setter method`?

Comment: @CuriousMind You do not need `setter` neither `constructor` when using `@Autowired` on a field. You have 3 ways to inject beans, `field injection` with `@Autowired`, `setter` injection and `constructor` injection, it's up to you to choose one.

Comment: That is my doubt, when we use `field injection` why it still calls `constructor`.

Comment: When using `field injection`, behind the scene the container constructs your object using the default constructor and then set the fields values.